# cucumber and junit have wrong amount of tests in jenkins (surefire)

Tags: maven, junit, jenkins, cucumber, surefire

When I try to use Cucumber and Junit together through Maven (surefire) then the report has wrong amount of tests. I have only 250 tests but Jenkins shows me 1200 test. So when I investigated it I could find only a reference that is the problem of surefire plugin.

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/322

How to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

I could only create hack with surefire. if you like you can use:

1. necessary to create the junit report by Cucumber to some folder (1) 'cucumber'
2. copy surefire reports (excluding Cucmber report generated by surefire) to some folder (2) 'surefire-reports-fixed'  where  cucumber generated the report.
3. copy cucumber junit-report from (1) to (2)
4. jenkins has to use the folder (2) 'surefire-reports-fixed'

example changes in Maven:

```
 <plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>change-bad-cucumber-test-file</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports-fixed</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target/cucumber</directory>
                                </resource>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</directory>
                                    <excludes>
                                        <exclude>**/*CucumberTest.*</exclude>
                                    </excludes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

changes in CucumberTest.java:

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@Cucumber.Options(format = { "pretty", "junit:target/cucumber/TEST-packageHereToClass.CucumberTest.xml", "json:target/cucumber.json" })
public class CucumberTest {
 ...
}
```

in jenkins set surefire folder for tests to (2) 'surefire-reports-fixed'

Answer (score 0):

The following links seem to be relevant.

Discussion of the core issue of step definitions counting as tests:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/577

Separate issue which, in comments, discusses that the fix for changing from counting steps as tests to counting scenarios as junit tests will be forthcoming but is tied to the Gherkin 3 development effort:

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/263

Comment: I could understand nobody cares of it. and for me it works using maven-surefire-plugin for 2.12 version without any changes in workflow described above, but it appears in the new version of surefire plugin (2.18.1 again it does not work).

Comment: maven-surefire-plugin for 2.12 works with junit in parallel only. the 2.18.1 works with testng without problem.

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me-
I added the cucumber-junit reporting format in @cucumbeOptions i.e - **"junit:target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml"** and next when I ran this in eclipse(Also in VSO) , the Junit reports were generated in the **TEST-TestSuite.xml** file with proper count.

Code below-->

```
    @CucumberOptions(
                features= {"src/test/resources/Features"},
                plugin   = {"pretty:STDOUT","html:Reports/cucumber-pretty","junit:target/surefire-reports/TEST-TestSuite.xml",               "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:Reports/Reporting/Quixxi_Report.html"},
                monochrome = true,
                dryRun=false
           )
```